# Button stacking in mobile styles too close

Tags: html, css, email, mobile

I'm trying to get the buttons in my mobile email to stop stacking on top of each other so closely. It looks good in desktop view, but mobile cuts out any space between the buttons.

I've tried adding padding-bottom and margin-bottoms, but they end up making the mobile buttons bigger but still touching.

```
   .buttonstyles {
      font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif !important;
      font-size: 16px !important;
      color: #FFFFFF !important;
      padding: 10px !important;
    }
```

This code is currently making the buttons touch.

[The buttons currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24uSd.png)

Comment: please share your markup as well.

Comment: Try to manage `margin-bottom` in mobile size media query...

Comment: are you working on email template?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work or else plz share your code..

**css**

```
.buttonstyles {
  display: inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try with this code.

```css
.buttonstyles {
      background:#000;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 10px ;
      margin:10px;
      float:left;
      border:none;
    }
```

```html
<button class="buttonstyles">Demo1</button>
<button class="buttonstyles">Demo2</button>
```